# Combobox Enablity

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid

I have two `ComboBox` controls inside my `DataGrid` and I want to set the `Enable` state of one `ComboBox` depending upon the selection of items in another.

Example:

I have a `ComboBox` named "Item" and another named "SerialNumber".  When I select any item from the respective drop-down, it changes the SerialNumber ComboBox collection accordingly.

What I want is when I select an item, and if there is no SerialNumber according to the selected item, I want to disable the "SerialNumber" `ComboBox`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to write good questions and provide us some code so we can see how you load the data into your ComboBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable your combobox if it is empty. Am I right?
to do so, you can create a converter

This is your combobox

```
<ComboBox [...]
   Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource HiddenWithNoElementConverter}}"  />
```

This is your resource to be able to use the resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:HiddenWithNoElementConverter x:Key="HiddenWithNoElementConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And this is your converter class

```
    class HiddenWithNoElementConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        if((value as IEnumerable<string>).Count() == 0)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }...
```